# Convert SNP data from GEO into PED and MAP files?

Tags: plink, format-conversion, geo, snp-chip

I can easily grab SNP-Chip data from NCBI's GEO database for a given Illumina SNP-Chip array, e.g. from here:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE52147

GEO provides data as [SOFT formatted family file(s)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/soft.html#format), [MINiML formatted family file(s)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/MINiML.html) or Series Matrix File(s).

I'm looking for a way to convert these into PED and MAP files for use in [PLINK](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13742-015-0047-8)...

Or does PLINK read these formats natively?

Comment: I see. Maybe PLINK cannot handle this. I see on GEO that series downloads are suitable for opening in spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't want to manually play with 3000 sheets...

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the 'contact us' email at GEO didn't help at all.

I ended up probably re-inventing the wheel with this script:
https://gist.github.com/CholoTook/60968e3ab6d90cb8fd19be55a25592f1

YMMV